# i am developing a simple movie list app using recycler view

Tags: android, interface, onclick, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am new to android so far I have created the recycler view with decorations but now I am unable set onClick listener in recycler view please help ... the first error is for clicklistener interface says

> clicklistener already defined in compilation unit

therefore the onclick and onlongclick methods also gives error....in main activity i am having errors at override says

> method does not override from its superclass

recycler touch listener code:

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }



}
main_activty:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter=new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        prepareMovieData();
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));


    }
    private void prepareMovieData(){

        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The Martian", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Up", "Animation", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Trek", "Science Fiction", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The LEGO Movie", "Animation", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Iron Man", "Action & Adventure", "2008");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Aliens", "Science Fiction", "1986");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Chicken Run", "Animation", "2000");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Back to the Future", "Science Fiction", "1985");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Action & Adventure", "1981");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Goldfinger", "Action & Adventure", "1965");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a custom implementation of the `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` Here is the code for it -

```
public class RecycleItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecycleItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Then use this custom `RecycleItemClickListener` like this -

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecycleItemClickListener(context, new RecycleItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                // TODO Handle item click

                            }
                        })
                );
```

This always works :)

Comment: thanks .. but where should i implement onItemTouchListener??

Comment: After you have done `recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)` Basically in the activity/fragment in which your recyclerView is set